# Update a variable on one computer an then display it on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it would be possible using javascript for one user to press a button to give another user "coins" it then updates the var playertwocoins, saves it to a text file in dropbox and then the person on the other computer gets a coin.

e.g.
User 1's computer

```
<button onclick="GiveCoin()">Give User 2 a coin</button<
<script>
var playertwocoins = 0
function GiveCoin() {
playertwocoins = playertwocoins + 1
}
```

Users 2's computer

```
<p id="Coins"></p>
<script>
var playtwocoins = 0
document.getelementbyid("Coins")innerHtml = playertwocoins
```

So when player one presses the button it updates player twos var. I only know HTML, JS, and little Jquery thanks

***Edit (2020):*** I've learned what a database is and my coworkers think this is funny.

Comment: Hi Puffy - this is possible try out Meteor https://www.meteor.com/install or Firebase https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html

Comment: ok i will try it out

Comment: Meteor seems just like what i need thanks :D

Comment: :) Awesome! good luck!